# client gives error 10060 when sending message to a TCP port

Tags: vb.net, windows, tcp, firewall, tcpclient

we are using a vb.net chat application which uses a TCP client to send message.it uses TCP port 25025.In some cases we get an error 10060 from client when sending message.Also the error is not continuous and is intermediate.In both PC windows firewall and antivirus firewall is off.To troubleshoot the problem i have tried telnet and netstat command and it worked without any error.what may be possible reasons for this error and how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Error 10060 is 'connection timed out'.

Check your timeout parameters for all sockets/TCP client/server objects.
Check that you are not looping somewhere waiting for a response, etc.

Without any source code or further information, other diagnosis is difficult!

Answer (score 0):

these are client side and server side code.
we get Error 10053 and 10061 also

Client side code
    in our application when user clicks 'send' message' button  this procedure will be called..
     Public Sub SendMessageByPort(ByVal PCName As String, ByVal Port As Integer, ByVal Message As String)
            Try
                'add winsock control added
                Dim TempWinClient As New AxMSWinsockLib.AxWinsock
                Me.Controls.Add(TempWinClient)
                AddHandler TempWinClient.CloseEvent, AddressOf TcpClient_CloseEvent
                AddHandler TempWinClient.ConnectEvent, AddressOf TcpClient_ConnectEvent
                AddHandler TempWinClient.DataArrival, AddressOf TcpClient_DataArrival
                AddHandler TempWinClient.Error, AddressOf TcpClient_Error

```
            TempWinClient.RemoteHost = PCName       
            TempWinClient.RemotePort = Port         
            TempWinClient.Tag = Message     
            TempWinClient.Connect()     

        Catch ex As Exception       
            Write_toErrorLog(ex.StackTrace, Err.Description, Err.Number, Me.Name, "UpdateToServer")     
        End Try     
    End Sub     


 Private Sub TcpClient_ConnectEvent(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     
        Try     
            sender.SendData(sender.tag)         
        Catch ex As Exception       
            Write_toErrorLog(ex.StackTrace, Err.Description, Err.Number, Me.Name, "WinClient_ConnectEvent")     
        End Try     
    End Sub     


Private Sub TcpClient_DataArrival(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_DataArrivalEvent)       
        Try     

            Dim TempStr As String = ""      
            Dim MsgID As String = "" '      
            Dim ErrorMsgstr As String = ""      

            sender.GetData(TempStr)     

            If TempStr.IndexOf("[ERROR]") >= 0 Then     
    MessageBox.Show("Error when Message send to " & sender.RemoteHost.ToString & " " & TempStr, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)    
            ElseIf TempStr.IndexOf("[SUCCESS]") >= 0 Then       
                MessageBox.Show("Message Sucssesfully sent to port", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)       
            Else        
                MessageBox.Show(TempStr, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)       
            End If      

            sender.Close()      
            Me.Controls.Remove(sender)      

        Catch ex As Exception       
            Write_toErrorLog(ex.StackTrace, Err.Description, Err.Number, Me.Name, "TcpClient_DataArrival")      
        End Try     
    End Sub     

 Private Sub TcpClient_CloseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)      
        Try     
            sender.Close()      
            Me.Controls.Remove(sender)      
        Catch ex As Exception       
            Write_toErrorLog(ex.StackTrace, Err.Description, Err.Number, Me.Name, "WinClient_CloseEvent")       
        End Try     
    End Sub     



  Private Sub TcpClient_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_ErrorEvent)     
        Try     
            Dim retryCnt As Integer     
            Dim MessageData As String = sender.tag      
            Dim RetryProcess As Boolean     
            Dim ErrorDetails As String = "Not Uploaded to Web because of connection failure in network " & sender.RemoteHost.ToString & ". DataSent:" & MessageData     

            'for this error we tried three times        
            If InStr(e.description, "Connection is aborted due to timeout or other failure", CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Then       
                retryCnt = Val(getArgColVal("RetryProcess", MessageData))       
                If retryCnt < 3 Then        
                    MessageData = Replace(MessageData, "#RetryProcess$" & retryCnt & "|", "", , , CompareMethod.Text)       
                    MessageData = MessageData & "#RetryProcess$" & (retryCnt + 1) & "|"     
                    RetryProcess = True     
                End If      
            End If      


            If RetryProcess = True Then 'retry sending message to port on error     
                Call SendMessageByPort(sender.RemoteHost.ToString, sender.RemotePort, MessageData)      
            Else        
                    Call Write_toErrorLog("", e.description, e.number, Me.Name, "TcpClient_Error", True, , , ErrorDetails) '        
                    Call MsgWinman("785", "sender" & MsgVarSep & "description" & MsgVarSep & "number", sender.RemoteHost.ToString & MsgVarSep & e.description & MsgVarSep & e.number)       
                End If      
            End If      

            sender.Close()      
            Me.Controls.Remove(sender)      
        Catch ex As Exception       
            Write_toErrorLog(ex.StackTrace, Err.Description, Err.Number, Me.Name, "TcpClient_Error") 'sod 19.9.13'Write_toErrorLog(ex.StackTrace, Err.Description, Err.Number, Me.Name, "WinClient_Error")      
        End Try     
    End Sub
```

Server side code
     'global variables
      Dim TempWebDetails() As WebUpLoadDetails
        Dim WinSocketArray As AxMSWinsockLib.AxWinsock() = New AxMSWinsockLib.AxWinsock() {}
        Dim WinSocketName() As String
        ''' 
        ''' 0-->Close,1-->Listen,2-->Others
        ''' 
        Dim WinSocketState() As Integer
        Dim WinTimer() As Integer

```
'frmpaydet is form name     
 Private Sub frmPayDet_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown      
        Try     
                    LoadNewSocket()     
                    ListenFreeSocket()      
                    Me.Hide()       
        Catch ex As Exception       
            Write_toErrorLog(ex.StackTrace, Err.Description, Err.Number, Me.Text, "frmPayDet_Shown")        
        End Try     
    End Sub     


 Private Sub LoadNewSocket()        
        Dim IsVisible As Boolean = Me.Visible       
        Try     
            Me.Visible = True       
            Dim i As Integer = WinSocketArray.GetUpperBound(0) + 1      
            ReDim Preserve WinSocketArray(i)        
            ReDim Preserve WinSocketState(i)        
            ReDim Preserve WinSocketName(i)     
            ReDim Preserve WinTimer(i)      
            WinSocketArray(i) = New AxMSWinsockLib.AxWinsock        
            WinSocketArray(i).Name = "WinServer" & i        
            WinSocketName(i) = WinSocketArray(i).Name       

            Me.Controls.Add(WinSocketArray(i))      
            AddHandler WinSocketArray(i).CloseEvent, AddressOf tcpServer_CloseEvent     
            AddHandler WinSocketArray(i).ConnectionRequest, AddressOf tcpServer_ConnectionRequest       
            AddHandler WinSocketArray(i).DataArrival, AddressOf tcpServer_DataArrival       
            AddHandler WinSocketArray(i).Error, AddressOf tcpServer_Error       
            ToolSeverCount.Text = " | WinSocket Count is " & i + 1 & " |"       

        Catch ex As Exception       
            Write_toErrorLog(ex.StackTrace, Err.Description, Err.Number, Me.Name, "LoadNewSocket")      
        Finally     
            Me.Visible = IsVisible      
        End Try     
    End Sub     

    Private Sub ListenFreeSocket()      
        On Error GoTo ListenFreeSocket_eh       

        Dim ListenFlg As Boolean        
        Timer1.Enabled = True       
        ToolServer.Text = ""        

        If WinSocketArray.Length > 0 Then       
            For i As Integer = 0 To WinSocketState.GetUpperBound(0)     
                If WinSocketState(i) = 1 Then       
                    ToolServer.Text = " | " & WinSocketArray(i).Name & " Sever Listen at Port " & WinSocketArray(i).LocalPort & " | "       
                    ListenFlg = True        
                    Exit For        
                End If      
            Next        

            'if not found then listen socket which is free      
            If ListenFlg = False Then       
                For i As Integer = 0 To WinSocketState.GetUpperBound(0)     
                    If WinSocketState(i) = 0 Then       
                        WinSocketArray(i).LocalPort = Split("PC110:8000", ":")(1)       
                        WinSocketArray(i).Listen()      
                        ToolServer.Text = " | " & WinSocketArray(i).Name & " Sever Listen at Port " & WinSocketArray(i).LocalPort & " | "       
                        WinSocketState(i) = 1       
                        If i = WinSocketState.GetUpperBound(0) Then LoadNewSocket()     
                        ListenFlg = True        
                        Exit For        
                    End If      
                Next        
            End If      
        End If      

        If ListenFlg = False Then       
            'Enable Timer       
            LoadNewSocket()     
            Timer1.Enabled = True       
        Else        
            'Disable Timer      
            Timer1.Enabled = False      
        End If      

        Exit Sub        
ListenFreeSocket_eh:        
        'Write_toErrorLog_old(Err.Description, Err.Number, Me.Name, "ListenFreeSocket")'this line must be commented     
End Sub     


Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick     
        Try     
            Call ListenFreeSocket()     
        Catch ex As Exception       
            Write_toErrorLog(ex.StackTrace, Err.Description, Err.Number, Me.Name, "Timer1_Tick")        
        End Try     
    End Sub     


Private Sub tcpServer_ConnectionRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_ConnectionRequestEvent) ' Handles tcpServer1.ConnectionRequest, tcpServer2.ConnectionRequest, tcpServer3.ConnectionRequest, tcpServer4.ConnectionRequest, tcpServer5.ConnectionRequest, tcpServer0.ConnectionRequest      
        Try     
            CloseWinSocket(sender.name)     
            sender.Accept(e.requestID)      
            ConnectWinSocket(sender.name)       
            ListenFreeSocket()      

            ToolStatus.Text = " | " & sender.RemoteHostIP & " IP Address Accepted | "       

        Catch ex As Exception       
            ToolServer.Text = ex.Message & " Please Call Coding Team"       
        End Try     
    End Sub     



 Private Sub CloseWinSocket(ByVal SocketName As String)     
        Try     
            If SocketName.Trim <> "" Then       
                Dim i As Integer = Array.IndexOf(WinSocketName, SocketName)     
                WinSocketArray(i).Close()       
                WinSocketState(i) = 0       
                WinTimer(i) = 0     
            Else        
                If Not WinSocketState Is Nothing Then       
                    For i As Integer = 0 To WinSocketState.GetUpperBound(0)     
                        If WinSocketState(i) <> 0 Then      
                            WinSocketArray(i).Close()       
                            WinSocketState(i) = 0       
                            WinTimer(i) = 0     
                        End If      
                    Next        
                End If      
            End If      

        Catch ex As Exception       
            Write_toErrorLog(ex.StackTrace, Err.Description, Err.Number, Me.Name, "CloseWinSocket")     
        End Try     

    End Sub     


 Private Sub ConnectWinSocket(ByVal SocketName As String)       
        Try     
            Dim i As Integer = Array.IndexOf(WinSocketName, SocketName)     
            WinSocketState(i) = 2       
        Catch ex As Exception       
            Write_toErrorLog(ex.StackTrace, Err.Description, Err.Number, Me.Name, "ConnectWinSocket")       
        End Try     
    End Sub     


Private Sub tcpServer_DataArrival(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_DataArrivalEvent)       
        Try     
            Dim TempStr As String = ""      
            Dim ReplyMessage As String = ""     
            sender.GetData(TempStr)     

            If TempStr Is Nothing Then TempStr = ""     

            If TempStr.Trim <> "" Then      
    ''some process is done  
    'ReplyMessage string assigned proper reply string   
    sender.SendData(ReplyMessage)   
            Else        
                CloseWinSocket(sender.name)     
                ToolStatus.Text = " | No Data Sent to IPAddress:- " & sender.RemoteHostIP & " | "       
            End If      

        Catch ex As Exception       
            Write_toErrorLog(ex.StackTrace, Err.Description, Err.Number, Me.Name, "tcpServer_DataArrival")      
        End Try     
    End Sub     


 Private Sub tcpServer_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_ErrorEvent)      
        Try     
            ToolServer.Text = e.description & " Please Call Coding Team"        
            CloseWinSocket(sender.name)     
            ListenFreeSocket()      
            ToolServer.Text = "Sever Listen on Local Port " & sender.LocalPort()        

        Catch ex As Exception       
            ToolServer.Text = ex.Message & " Please Call Coding Team"       
        End Try     
    End Sub     


Private Sub tcpServer_CloseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       
        Try     
            CloseWinSocket(sender.name)     
            ListenFreeSocket()      
        Catch ex As Exception       
            ToolServer.Text = ex.Message & " Please Call Coding Team"       
        End Try     
       End sub
```